# Isotope insert element into specific position

Tags: jquery-isotope

I'm trying to insert a new item into a specific position in isotope.  Basically when an isotope item is clicked on, I want to add a full container width item at the start of the next row.  It could even be an item that already exists and is hidden.

Here is the fiddle I was working on: http://jsfiddle.net/AAnrX/62/.

```
$(function(){  
  var $container = $('.isotope'); 
  var $checkboxes = $('#filters input');

  // init isotope, then insert all items from hidden #alpha
  $container.isotope({
    itemSelector: '.item' 
  }).isotope();


  $checkboxes.change(function(){
    var filters = [];
    // get checked checkboxes values
    $checkboxes.filter(':checked').each(function(){
      filters.push( this.value );
    });
    filters = filters.join(', ');
    $container.isotope({ filter: filters });
  });

  $('#shuffle').click(function(){
    $container.isotope('shuffle');
  });

    var $cell = $('.item');

    $cell.click(function () {       
        $('#box').insertAfter('#first');
        $container.isotope('reLayout');
    });    
});
```

Essentially what I have will change the item's location in the DOM, but that doesn't affect how isotope positions it I guess.  I have tried reLayout and layout after changing it, but I'm not having much luck.

Comment: Did you achieve this?

Answer (score 2):

Apparently the instead of `$container.isotope('reLayout')` I needed to use `$('.isotope').isotope('reloadItems').isotope({ sortBy: 'original-order' });` Upon reload the item is correctly repositioned in the isotope order.